# Nodemailer and Godaddy, I've tried every solution to no avail

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, godaddy-api

I bought a domain and an email adrees with GoDaddy with Office 365 Basic bundled with it.

I'm trying from a few days to send just an email with nodemailer from my node app without ever succeding because I always get a `535 Authentication Failed from user@domain.com`.

I've scanned StackOverflow for days trying every solution, this is every setting I've tried to pass to nodemailer.createTransport:

```
const mailerConfig = 
{
    //First set of parameters tried
    service: 'Godaddy',
    host: "smtp.office365.com",  
    secureConnection: true,
    port: 587,

    auth: 
    {
        user: "user@domain.com",
        pass: "password" 
    }


    //Second set of parameters tried
    host: "smtp.office365.com",
    secureConnection: false,
    port: "587",
    auth:
    {
        user : "user@domain.com",
        pass : "password"
    },
    tls:
    {
        ciphers:'SSLv3'
    }


    //Third set of parameters tried
    service: "outlook",
    auth: 
    {
        user: 'user@domain.com',
        pass: 'password'
    }
}
```

None of these three settings worked, someone has any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: did you solve this?  I am getting 'Error: Invalid login: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [BYAPR07CA0061.namprd07.prod.outlook.com]'

Answer (score 2):

There is a [godaddy FAQ entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20210119022809/https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-configure-email-set-up-on-thunderbird-28020) called "Manually configure email set up on Thunderbird" (which seems to be only accessible via WaybackMachine).

It mentions the following configuration:

```
Incoming (IMAP): imap.secureserver.net    993     SSL  Normal password
Outgoing (SMTP): smtpout.secureserver.net 465,587 SSL  Normal password
```

and

```
Username: Workspace Email address
```

Using the above, especially `smtpout.secureserver.net` as SMTP Host works for me – tested with godaddy email in 2021.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still having issues, this config is working for me actually in Sept 2021:

```
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtpout.secureserver.net",
    port: 587, // port for secure SMTP
    auth: {
      user: "youremailaddress",
      pass: "yourpassword",
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You must enable SMTP login for the O365 mailbox or user in the admin settings

[image]

[image]

2. If the user has multifactor turned on, then you need to use "app password", normal password won't work if MFA is enabled.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/multi-factor-authentication-end-user-app-passwords

3. You need to disable security defaults or adjust Conditional Access policies.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults

4. Also, you can debug issue using sign-in logs in azure user account.

[image]

Comment: i can't see to get to the O365 admin settings, i just get redirected to GoDaddy's limited interface

Comment: where do you 'enable SMTP login for the O365 mailbox' in godaddy?

Comment: godaddy O365 i'm not sure... I only did it using Microsoft 365 account..

Comment: I added screenshot for M365 admin panel above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable all access  [image]

and don't forget to disable the sms/call confirmation for the login

by the way this code i used on firebase cloud function/nodemailer

```
  cors(req, res, async () => {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.office365.com",
      port: 587, // port for secure SMTP
      auth: {
        user: "user@domain.com",
        pass: "password",
      },
      tls: {
        ciphers: 'SSLv3'
      }

    });

    if (req.method === 'POST') {
      var mailOptions = {
        from:req.body.from,
        to: req.body.email, // list of receivers
        subject: req.body.subject, // Subject line
        text: req.body.text,
      };
      return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
        res.status(200).send('Email has been sent to mr/ms : ' + req.body.email); return ("mail sent")
      });
    }
  })
```